# Given mu and sigma of a normal distribution, how to find min and max?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

[image: normal distribution of mu=0, sigma-0.02]

I am trying to calculate the min and max values for Gaussian noise where mu=0 and sigma=0.02.  It looks like it is 0.08 and -0.08 from the picture from https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/normal.html but what is the math behind it?

Comment: There is no min and max for a Gaussian distribution. It is possible to get any real number from a Gaussian distribution (although it is very unlikely to get values far from the mean).

Comment: @angryavian thank you for the clarification.  Based on that I am going to use + or - 0.08 to cover most of the cases.

Comment: That should be fine. The probability of getting a number more than $4$ standard deviations from the mean is less than $0.0001$.

Comment: @angryavian if you have any links to math resources that explains how to work this all out, please post a comment.

Comment: https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/z-score/